# How to append object-key value form one array to other array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have an existing array with multiple object. With an interval I would like to update the existing array with values from another array. See the (simplified) example below.

I've serverall gools:

1. Copy the value of fan_count form the new array, to the current array with the key "fan_count_new"
2. If a object is removed or added in the New array, it have to do the same to the Current array.

As far I can see now, I can use some es6 functions :) like:

1. [object-assign](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/object-assign-es6/), but how to set the new key "fan_count_new"?
2. How to loop through the array to compare and add or remove + copy the fan_count?

**Current array:**

```
[{
    "fan_count": 1234,
    "id": "1234567890",
    "picture": {
        "data": {
            "url": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/photo.png"
        }
    }
},
{
    "fan_count": 4321,
    "id": "09876543210",
    "picture": {
        "data": {
            "url": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/photo.png"
        }
    }
}, ...
]
```

**New array:**

```
[{
    "fan_count": 1239,
    "picture": {
        "data": {
            "url": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/photo.png"
        }
    "id": "1234567890"
},
{
    "fan_count": 4329,
    "picture": {
        "data": {
            "url": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/photo.png"
        }
    },
    "id": "09876543210"
}, ...
]]
```

Comment: Only update `fan_count` or will items also be different so you need to add and remove items also?

Comment: is `fan_count` unique?

Comment: @AndrzejSmyk not according to examples. It seems to be a dynamic value whereas `id` appears to be unique

Comment: @charlietfl: there are other values who can change as well, like the picture. But first I would like to understand the first step. As I write now; then I can also make it the other way around: only copy the fan_cound_old to the New array and use it instead. What did you have in mind?

Comment: @AndrzejSmyk; yes.

Comment: Then you really need to provide full and specific details of what you need and what all the criteria are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove elements which doesn't exists in new array by using array.filter and you can loop through the new array to update the same object in the current array:

```js
var currArr = [
    {
        "fan_count": 1234,
        "id": "1234567890",
    },
    {
        "fan_count": 4321,
        "id": "09876543210",
    },
    {
        "fan_count": 4321,
        "id": "09876543215",
    }
];

var newArr = [
    {
        "fan_count": 1234,
        "id": "1234567890"
    },
    {
        "fan_count": 5555,
        "id": "09876543210"
    }
];

currArr = currArr.filter(obj => newArr.some(el => el.id === obj.id));

newArr.forEach(obj => {
    var found = currArr.find(o => o.id === obj.id);
    if (found) {
        found.fan_count_new = obj.fan_count;
    }
});

console.log(currArr);
```

Later on I realised that is was better to turn it around, add the fan_count form the currArr to the new one. This because it is easier to handle new objects, and you dont't have to deal with deleted objects. So, anybody how is looking for something like this:

```
newArr.forEach(obj => {
  var found = currArr.find(o => o.id === obj.id);
  if (found) {
    console.log('found: ', found.fan_count, obj.fan_count)
    obj.fan_count_prev = found.fan_count;
    obj.fan_count_diff = Math.round(obj.fan_count - found.fan_count);
  }

  if (typeof obj.fan_count_prev === "undefined") {
    obj.fan_count_prev = obj.fan_count;
    obj.fan_count_diff = 0
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it as soon as possible in my code